# declaring method inside a constructor

Tags: methods, constructor

when i declare the method inside a constructor i'm getting error "; expected". Not sure why. could you please help me understand

```
public class Reservation {
Date arrivalDate = new Date();
  Date departDate = new Date();
  Reservation(Date arrDate, Date deptDate)
   {
    arrivalDate = arrDate;
    departDate = deptDate;
    long nightsStay();
   }
 void nightsStay()
  {
      long days = (departDate.getTime()-arrivalDate.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000);
  }
```

I'm getting error on the line where I declared long nightsStay();

Comment: What should `long nightsStay();` do? There is the error.

Comment: it should store the number of days between departure and arrival dates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do

```
long nightsStay();
```

If you define a variable you need a name and then you can point a value to it, but you are missing the name.

```
public class Reservation {
   Date arrivalDate = new Date();
   Date departDate = new Date();
   long nightsStay;  // add that line

   Reservation(Date arrDate, Date deptDate)
   {
      arrivalDate = arrDate;
      departDate = deptDate;
      nightsStay = nightsStay();  // change that line
    }

   long nightsStay()
   {
      long days = (departDate.getTime()-arrivalDate.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000);
   }
}
```

Examples:

```
long l = 5;  //variable l gets value 5;
l = nightsStay();   // calling method nightsStay and storing the result in l;
long nightsStay(); // is neither one
```

And if you want the method `nightsStay()` to return something then you must change the return type from `void` to the type you like to return, which is `long` in your case.

Comment: @juergen... thanks.. it worked. Could you please explain what's wrong with the code I wrote. Can't i just declare a method inside a constructore.

Comment: There's a naming conflict - `nightsStay` cannot be both a `long` and a `void ()`.

Comment: @michaelb958 I tried using long nightsStay(); inside the constructor and implemented the method without void - long nightsStay() and returned days. even then I'm getting the same error as "; expected" on the line inside the constructore where i declared this method

Comment: Got it guyz. I realized my mistake. If I declare the method without the return type it works. Thanks a ton for answering and helping me realize my mistake